# How do authenticate nuget proxy for conect nexus

Tags: visual-studio-2013, proxy, installation, nuget, nexus

I'm setting NuGet for deploy my projects in Nexus, when I execute the command 'nuget install ' i got this message:

Name User:INFO: An error occurred while loading packages from 'MyRepository' Could Not Ask for an entry in Interactive Mode NO. Provide the credentials for 'MyRepository'

How should I configure proxy, userLogin and password network, to make it work?